# Coldfusion consume Dynamics NAV Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, dynamics-nav

I am trying to consume a Dynamics NAV web service from within Coldfusion. However it fails with this message:

> ...   {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:401 ...

I have tested the same web service from within a C# project and this works like a charm. So its truly a security issue.

There is quite some discussion on the internet about calling Dynamics NAV webservices, see for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk

The problem seems to be how to make Coldfusion use NTLM authentication. There is a post on this topic at [NTLM Authentication in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895361/ntlm-authentication-in-coldfusion), but I'm failing to see how to implement this when calling webservices from Coldfusion.

It is possible to create an intermediate service with C# and call this service from within Coldfusion. But I am looking at a direct approach.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Axis (the web server used in ColdFusion) supports only basic authentication, but NAV only supports Windows authentication (NTLM or negotiate, depending on the value of the server config key WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication).

I found [this](http://tjordahl.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/apache-axis-and-commons-httpclient.html) page which describes a workaround. Just in case the link dies, the workaround is to configure Axis to use the Jakarta Commons HTTPClient library.

You need to edit the client-config.wsdd Axis config file, and change this line:

```
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />;
```

to this:

```
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender" />;
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. Looks promising and I will get back after testing!